# Getting unable to cast object of type exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

This problem has just appeared, but I haven't modified the code associated with this. So not really sure how to go about fixing it.

Here is the short message:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType16`2[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel]]'
>   to type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType4`2[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel]]'.

Here is the full exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType16`2[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel]]'
>   to type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType4`2[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Nop.Web.Models.Media.PictureModel]]'.
>   at Nop.Core.Caching.MemoryCacheManager.Get[T](String key) at
>   Nop.Core.Caching.CacheExtensions.Get[T](ICacheManager cacheManager,
>   String key, Int32 cacheTime, Func`1 acquire) at
>   Nop.Core.Caching.CacheExtensions.Get[T](ICacheManager cacheManager,
>   String key, Func`1 acquire) at
>   Nop.Web.Controllers.ProductController.PrepareProductDetailsPageModel(Product
>   product, ShoppingCartItem updatecartitem, Boolean isAssociatedProduct,
>   Nullable`1 childProductId) at
>   Nop.Web.Controllers.ProductController.ProductDetails(Int32 productId,
>   String c, String s, Int32 updatecartitemid) at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   ControllerBase , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)

HEre is the code the exception is pointing to:

```
model.DefaultPictureZoomEnabled = _mediaSettings.DefaultPictureZoomEnabled;
        //default picture
        var defaultPictureSize = isAssociatedProduct
            ? _mediaSettings.AssociatedProductPictureSize
            : _mediaSettings.ProductDetailsPictureSize;
        //prepare picture models
        var productPicturesCacheKey = string.Format(ModelCacheEventConsumer.PRODUCT_DETAILS_PICTURES_MODEL_KEY,
            product.Id, defaultPictureSize, isAssociatedProduct, _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id,
            _webHelper.IsCurrentConnectionSecured(), _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
        var cachedPictures = _cacheManager.Get(productPicturesCacheKey, () =>
        {
            var pictures = _pictureService.GetPicturesByProductId(product.Id);
            var defaultPicture = pictures.FirstOrDefault();
            var defaultPictureModel = new PictureModel
            {
                ImageUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(defaultPicture, defaultPictureSize, !isAssociatedProduct),
                FullSizeImageUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(defaultPicture, 0, !isAssociatedProduct),
                Title =
                    string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageLinkTitleFormat.Details"),
                        model.Name),
                AlternateText =
                    string.Format(
                        _localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageAlternateTextFormat.Details"),
                        model.Name),
            };
            //"title" attribute
            defaultPictureModel.Title = (defaultPicture != null &&
                                         !string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultPicture.TitleAttribute))
                ? defaultPicture.TitleAttribute
                : string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageLinkTitleFormat.Details"),
                    model.Name);
            //"alt" attribute
            defaultPictureModel.AlternateText = (defaultPicture != null &&
                                                 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultPicture.AltAttribute))
                ? defaultPicture.AltAttribute
                : string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageAlternateTextFormat.Details"),
                    model.Name);

            //all pictures
            var pictureModels = new List<PictureModel>();
            foreach (var picture in pictures)
            {
                var pictureModel = new PictureModel
                {
                    ImageUrl =
                        _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(picture,
                            _mediaSettings.ProductThumbPictureSizeOnProductDetailsPage),
                    FullSizeImageUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(picture),
                    Title =
                        string.Format(
                            _localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageLinkTitleFormat.Details"),
                            model.Name),
                    AlternateText =
                        string.Format(
                            _localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageAlternateTextFormat.Details"),
                            model.Name),
                };
                //"title" attribute
                pictureModel.Title = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(picture.TitleAttribute)
                    ? picture.TitleAttribute
                    : string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageLinkTitleFormat.Details"),
                        model.Name);
                //"alt" attribute
                pictureModel.AlternateText = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(picture.AltAttribute)
                    ? picture.AltAttribute
                    : string.Format(
                        _localizationService.GetResource("Media.Product.ImageAlternateTextFormat.Details"),
                        model.Name);

                pictureModels.Add(pictureModel);
            }

            return new {DefaultPictureModel = defaultPictureModel, PictureModels = pictureModels};
        });
        model.DefaultPictureModel = cachedPictures.DefaultPictureModel;
        model.PictureModels = cachedPictures.PictureModels;
```

I tried to send the pictures to a list like so but it didn't work.

```
var pictures = _pictureService.GetPicturesByProductId(product.Id).ToList();
```

Anyone know what might be going on here, I have never run into these type of errors before.
Thanks

Comment: Can you recreate this in a smaller block of code?

Comment: @Ben I wouldn't even know where to begin recreating this

Comment: The error is coming due to trying to cast similar anonymous types (similar to us but not to compiler). Your method `_cacheManager.Get()` returns a anonymous type, what is the return type of `_pictureService.GetPictureUrl()` ? A good way to debug would be to create the lambda in `_cacheManager.Get()` as its own method, so you can debug through and check the values that are coming.

Comment: @peeyushsingh the `_pictureService.GetPictureUrl()` returns a string with the img src

Comment: Sorry I meant, `GetPicturesByProductId`, does it return an anonymous type, basically the errors means somewhere you are trying to cast one anonymous type into another, if you can figure out where this is happening you will find the problem you need to solve.

Comment: @peeyushsingh Thanks for the help :) The method returns a IList `public virtual IList<Picture> GetPicturesByProductId(int productId, int recordsToReturn = 0)`